# React useScroll Hook keep track of previousScrollTop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scroll, react-context, scrolltop

So I've followed this:
https://www.pinkdroids.com/blog/moving-header-react-hooks-context/

And managed to get it working on one app.

I'm not replicating what I did in another app and it's not working.

I've got as far as working out that my previousScrollTop and currentScrollTop are always the same – therefore no direction is being added

But why are they the same!!!

I've gone as far as copy and pasting the code so no issues there.

Could this be a problem with memo?

with my lodash import?

Not getting any errors.

UPDATE*

The problem is either with useMemo, or useRef in my useScroll hook.

```
const getScrollPosition = () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return 0
    }
    return (
        window.pageYOffset ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
        document.body.scrollTop ||
        0
    )
}

export const useScroll = (timeout = 250) => {
    const defaultScrollTop = useMemo(() => getScrollPosition(), [])
    const previousScrollTop = useRef(defaultScrollTop)
    const [currentScrollTop, setCurrentScrollTop] = useState(defaultScrollTop)
    console.log(currentScrollTop)



useEffect(() => {
        const handleDocumentScroll = () => {
            const scrollTop = getScrollPosition()
            setCurrentScrollTop(scrollTop)
            console.log(currentScrollTop)
            previousScrollTop.current = scrollTop
            console.log(previousScrollTop.current)
        }

        const handleDocumentScrollThrottled = throttle(handleDocumentScroll, timeout)
        document.addEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled)
        }
    }, [timeout])



    return {
        scrollTop: currentScrollTop,
        previousScrollTop: previousScrollTop.current,
        time: timeout,
    }
}
```

UPDATE*

I've managed to work a fix with a setTimeout inside my handleDocumentScroll... Should delay between the values...

But still unsure why this worked before as it was and not now....

```
const handleDocumentScroll = () => {
        const scrollTop = getScrollPosition()
        setCurrentScrollTop(scrollTop)
        setTimeout(function () {
            previousScrollTop.current = scrollTop
        }, 200); // update previous 200ms after event fires
    }
```

Comment: I should also add that I'm using react v 18.1 in app where this scroll isn't working and 17.0.2 in the one that is...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.